# How to generate an EditResponseUrl() for manually entered rows in a Google Form response spreadheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have an spreadsheet linked with a form and made it as, all the user to edit the response after submit. And connected it with Awesome Table. When i insert a data through the form, the spreadsheet automatically generate the edit response url. this is done by gas. This isworking fine. But, what i want now is, how can i generate the response url for the data which i paste directly to the sheet from another sheet? is it possible? please help me with some suggestions or a piece of code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do this.

The forms services and the sheets service are two separate services. This is a simplified version of what happens when you submit a response to a form:

1. The form is submitted.
2. The forms service stores the response.
3. The forms service writes the response to a sheet.

When you use the EditResponseURL() method, you're getting the information from step 2), and editing it. This then causes the form to complete step 3) a second time, updating the sheet.

If you write the response directly to the sheet, you're skipping step 1) & 2). If the response is not stored in the form, there's no way to use the EditResponseURL() (As this is a forms only method).

Easy solution: Submit everything via the form, and do not write directly to the sheet.

More complicated solution: Write a custom form that allows you to pull the information in a range of cells from a sheet, update the information, then writes the edited information back to the sheet.

Comment: Thank you HDCerberus. Thanks for the suggestion. It will save my time on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The second Sheet would need to "know" what it was looking for.  The second sheet can retrieve anything it needs from the first sheet, but it needs information about what to retrieve.  You would need to explicitly record information that matches some kind of key to the information that should be retrieved.  The first Sheet could have information on what response is matched to what row of information.  You could have an ID that was just sequential numbers, or you could have an ID (key) that encoded the user name, the date, the time, a random number, a row number, etc. if you need/want that.  Your essentially designing a database structure.
It might help to define a flow chart of the process.

Comment: Thank you Sandy Good, but i couldn't get you. The second sheet is completely a random one.